# Replacing 2 ceiling fans with new remote style

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I have 2 fans on the same circuit with 2 separate switches, Not fan/light, switches are in separate rooms, either one would turn the fans on. Both fans are installed one works one does not. The non working fan has dual black and white wires

Comment: Pictures are always helpful. Some of the before you removed the old fans pictures would be great.

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a _Question_ and Answer forum, not a general discussion board. So far, you've made several statements, but you haven't asked any questions. Please [edit] to clearly indicate what your question is. Also, please clarify the existing situation, as it is very unclear what the current situation is. Are the new fans installed, one works, one doesn't? What does "remote style" mean? What wiring does the working fan have? So many questions, so few characters...